# Is there a way to access files that are created by a code on heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a discord bot that saves JSON files on the same directory he is in so it could work on more than one server without colliding (he saves variables that are not important to the question) .

I finished my code and I uploaded it to heroku for hosting. The thing is , when I ran the code from my pc I could see the files that were being created for each server for testing but now I don't know how to reach them.

Is there a way to check all the files I have in heroku?
(when I mean all, I mean also the JSON files that were created from the bot itself)

side not:
You can do `heroku run bash -a APPNAME` but it still doesn't let me see the files that were made in the dyno or directory.

On top of that, if someone has another good hosting site(preferred free) which doesn't use a ephemeral filesystem, that would be great if you can comment them down bellow.
(or if you have a way to save the files before the dyno deletes them)

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for in Heroku is called [Heroku Exec (SSH Tunneling)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec) which you can use to SSH into running dynos for debugging purposes.